# how to set series position in chartarea in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

`  For i = 0 To s_rating.Length - 2      'column length
Dim parts() As String = s_rating(i).Trim().Split(":"c)

```
                If i < ListView1.Items.Count Then
                    If ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count > 3 Then
                        ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text = parts(0).Trim()
                    Else
                        ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add(parts(0).Trim())
                    End If
                    If ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count > 4 Then
                        ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(4).Text = parts(1).Trim()
                    Else
                        ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add(parts(1).Trim())
                    End If

                Else
                    Dim data As New ListViewItem("")
                    data.SubItems.Add(parts(0).Trim()) ' Name
                    data.SubItems.Add(parts(1).Trim()) ' Value
                    ListView1.Items.Add(data)
                End If

                If ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count > 4 Then
                    ' Create a new ChartArea
                    Dim chartArea As New ChartArea()
                    Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea)

                    'Set the position of the pie chart within the ChartArea
                    'chartArea.Position = New ElementPosition(10, 10, 15, 15)

                    'Set the inner plot position to control the size of the pie chart
                    'chartArea.InnerPlotPosition = New ElementPosition(1, 1, 5, 5)

                    ' Creating a new Series of pie chart
                    Dim series As New Series()
                        series.ChartArea = chartArea.Name
                        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie

                        If parts(1).Trim() = "Excellent" Then
                            ' Add data points to the series
                            Dim excellentDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                                    .Label = "Excellent",
                                    .Color = Color.Green,
                                    .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                                    .BorderColor = Color.Black
                                }
                            Dim goodDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                                    .Label = "",
                                    .Color = Color.Green,
                                    .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                                    .BorderColor = Color.Black
                                }
                            Dim averageDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                                    .Label = "",
                                    .Color = Color.Green,
                                    .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                                    .BorderColor = Color.Black
                                }
                            Dim poorDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                                    .Label = "",
                                    .Color = Color.Green,
                                    .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                                    .BorderColor = Color.Black
                                    }

                            'Add the data point to your series
                            series.Points.Add(excellentDataPoint)
                            series.Points.Add(goodDataPoint)
                            series.Points.Add(averageDataPoint)
                            series.Points.Add(poorDataPoint)

                            'series.Points.Add(otherDataPoint)

                            'For Each point As DataPoint In Series.Points
                            '    If point IsNot excellentDataPoint Then
                            '        point.Color = Color.Gray
                            '    End If
                            'Next
                        End If
                    ' Add the series to the chart
                    Chart1.Series.Add(series)
                End If

                    If ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count > 4 Then
                    ' Create a new ChartArea
                    Dim chartArea As New ChartArea()
                    Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea)
                    ' Create a new Series of pie chart
                    Dim series1 As New Series()
                    series1.ChartArea = chartArea.Name
                    series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie

                    If parts(1).Trim() = "Good" Then

                        Dim excellentDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                            .Label = "",
                            .Color = Color.Green,
                            .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                            .BorderColor = Color.Black
                                }
                        ' Add data points to the series
                        Dim goodDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                                .Label = "Good",
                                .Color = Color.Green,
                                .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                                .BorderColor = Color.Black
                            }

                        Dim averageDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                                    .Label = "",
                                    .Color = Color.Gray,
                                    .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                                    .BorderColor = Color.Black
                                }
                        Dim poorDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                                .Label = "",
                                .Color = Color.Gray,
                                .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                                .BorderColor = Color.Black
                            }
                        'Dim otherDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 20) With {
                        '        .LegendText = "Others",
                        '        .Label = "Others",
                        '        .Color = Color.Green
                        '    }

                        ' Add the data point to your series
                        series1.Points.Add(excellentDataPoint)
                        series1.Points.Add(goodDataPoint)
                        series1.Points.Add(averageDataPoint)
                        series1.Points.Add(poorDataPoint)
                        ' Add the series to the chart
                        Chart1.Series.Add(series1)
                    End If
                End If

                If ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count > 4 Then
                    ' Create a new ChartArea
                    Dim chartArea As New ChartArea()
                    Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea)
                    ' Create a new Series of pie chart
                    Dim series2 As New Series()
                    series2.ChartArea = chartArea.Name
                    series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie

                    If parts(1).Trim() = "Average" Then
                        Dim excellentDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                        .Label = "",
                        .Color = Color.Gray,
                        .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                        .BorderColor = Color.Black
                            }
                        Dim goodDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                                .Label = "",
                                .Color = Color.Gray,
                                .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                                .BorderColor = Color.Black
                            }
                        ' Add data points to the series
                        Dim averageDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                            .Label = "Average",
                            .Color = Color.Green,
                            .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                            .BorderColor = Color.Black
                        }
                        Dim poorDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                            .Label = "",
                            .Color = Color.Gray,
                            .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                            .BorderColor = Color.Black
                        }
                        'Dim otherDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 20) With {
                        '        .LegendText = "Others",
                        '        .Label = "Others",
                        '        .Color = Color.Green
                        '    }

                        ' Add the data point to your series
                        series2.Points.Add(excellentDataPoint)
                        series2.Points.Add(goodDataPoint)
                        series2.Points.Add(averageDataPoint)
                        series2.Points.Add(poorDataPoint)
                        ' Add the series to the chart
                        Chart1.Series.Add(series2)
                    End If
                End If

                If ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count > 4 Then
                    ' Create a new ChartArea
                    Dim chartArea As New ChartArea()
                    Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea)
                    ' Create a new Series of pie chart
                    Dim series3 As New Series()
                    series3.ChartArea = chartArea.Name
                    series3.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
                    If parts(1).Trim() = "Poor" Then

                        Dim excellentDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                        .Label = "",
                        .Color = Color.Gray,
                        .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                        .BorderColor = Color.Black
                            }
                        Dim goodDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                                .Label = "",
                                .Color = Color.Gray,
                                .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                                .BorderColor = Color.Black
                            }
                        Dim averageDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                            .Label = "",
                            .Color = Color.Gray,
                            .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                            .BorderColor = Color.Black
                        }
                        ' Add data points to the series
                        Dim poorDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 25) With {
                            .Label = "Poor",
                            .Color = Color.Gray,
                            .IsVisibleInLegend = False,
                            .BorderColor = Color.Black
                        }
                        'Dim otherDataPoint As New DataPoint(0, 20) With {
                        '        .LegendText = "Others",
                        '        .Label = "Others",
                        '        .Color = Color.Green
                        '    }

                        ' Add the data point to your series
                        series3.Points.Add(excellentDataPoint)
                        series3.Points.Add(goodDataPoint)
                        series3.Points.Add(averageDataPoint)
                        series3.Points.Add(poorDataPoint)
                        ' Add the series to the chart
                        Chart1.Series.Add(series3)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
```

I am trying to generate multiple series inside a chart area. As of now, it is generating pie charts at different positions inside the chart area but I want to get each pie chart at fixed position.`